# How to capture multiple groups which include one or multiple arbitrary words using regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following string:

```
Notable foos in bar: Baz Buzz Plaza (A), Quox Shopping Center (B), Fizzbuzz Industrial Park (C), Fee Fi Town Hall (D), Fo Fum Fire Department Station 1 Headquarters (E). Display their locations in a map.
```

I need to capture the following regex groups in Ruby:

- `Baz Buzz Plaza`
- `Quox Shopping Center`
- `Fizzbuzz Industrial Park`
- `Fee Fi Town Hall`
- `Fo Fum Fire Department Station 1 Headquarters`

I can't seem to come up with the right pattern.  Here's the most successful of all the patterns I've tried:

```
/([\w|\s]+\(A\)|\(B\)|\(C\)|\(D\)|\(E\)|\(F\)|\(G\)[,|\.])+/
```

Which results in:

```
Match 1
1.  Baz Buzz Plaza (A)
Match 2
1.  (B)
Match 3
1.  (C)
Match 4
1.  (D)
Match 5
1.  (E)
```

I'm confused about why the pattern only matches the text I want for the first match group, and only returns the letters in parentheses for the remaining groups.

At this point I would settle for including the single letters in parentheses at the end of each match group, because I'm confident I could then strip those out in a subsequent step.  But the ideal outcome would be the above results I mentioned.

EDIT- as requested, the rules for my capture are that I need to capture every phrase after `Notable foos in bar:`, not including the single letter in parentheses, the space beforehand, or the punctuation after.  Each phrase could be single word or multiple words, and each word within the phrase could be an arbitrary word, pronoun, or number.  The phrase at the end (`Display their locations in a map.`) need not be captured.

Source: [Rubular.com](https://www.rubular.com)

Comment: Please confirm (and update) the input string's format. It appears there's line-breaks because the source contained them so I maintained what was there, but they can affect how we write a pattern. Note: quote formatting is for actual quotes, not for string representation which should be marked as `\`code\``. See the formatting help for more information. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)".

Comment: You have not stated the rules for identifying the substrings you wish to capture. You have only given an example which could be produced using a variety of rules. To illustrate what I mean by "rules", I began my answer by stating what I assumed are the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've updated the string to remove the newlines, and updated the question to include the rules for determining what to capture.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that each substring to be extracted:

- is preceded by `': '` or `'), '`; and
- is followed by `' ('` or `'.'`, the period being at the end of the string.

```
str = "Notable foos in bar: Baz Buzz Plaza (A), Quox Center (B), " +
      "Fizzbuzz Industrial Park (C), Fee Fi Town Hall (D), " +
      "Fo Fum Fire Department Station 1 Headquarters (E). " + 
      "Display their locations in a map (F), " +
      "I've added this string."
```

Note that I modified the string given in the question to add a clause at the end that I assume should be extracted.

```
str.scan /(?<=: |\), ).+?(?= \(|\.\z)/
  #=> ["Baz Buzz Plaza",
  #    "Quox Shopping Center",
  #    "Fizzbuzz Industrial Park",
  #    "Fee Fi Town Hall",
  #    "Fo Fum Fire Department Station 1 Headquarters",
  #    "I've added this string"]
```

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting:

```
r = /
    (?<=:\ |\),\ ) # match ': ' or '), ' in a positive lookbehind
    .+?            # match one or more characters lazily 
    (?=\ \(|\.\z)  # match ' (' or '.' at the end of the string 
                   # in a positive lookahead
    /x             # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

In free-spacing mode, spaces must be protected, else they will be stripped out by the parser before the expression is evaluated. I've done that by escaping them. Alternatively, a space could be placed by itself in an atomic group (`[ ]`) or one could use a Unicode expression such as `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

`([\w][\w ]*)\([A-Z]\)` seems to do what you want.

See it in action: https://rubular.com/r/4O5Kg4gfIFSDId

Comment: Use care with `\w`. It's the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` `_` isn't part of the requirement. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` would be more appropriate. `\w` actually is most appropriate for variable names.

Comment: Indeed. I went with the shorter form since it seemed unlikely that underscore was going to be an undesirable character in a place name, though.

Comment: Further to @theTinMan's comment, it may be appropriate to use Unicode's `[[:alnum:]]` or `\p{Alnum}`. Note that `[\w]` is the same as `\w` and your first match (for example) is `"Baz Buzz Plaza (A)"` but `"Baz Buzz Plaza"` is wanted.

Comment: Agreed. I'd go with `[[:alnum:]]`.

Comment: "...it seemed unlikely that underscore was going to be an undesirable character...", yes, but that's exactly how bugs occur, right? Unfortunately, programming is about exactly what we told it to do, not what we wanted it to do. And then we're awake at 3-4AM wondering WTF!?